# How do I fill an array with images?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, fill

This is my first time posting, so please be gracious if I'm doing something wrong, and thanks for your help!

I feel like I've read all the tutorials and questions but still can't seem to get this array filling with images.

I figured it out! Thanks to those of you who helped.

```js
    var titleOptions = ["<image src='images/spelling/cat.png' class='cardimg'>", "<image src='images/spelling/bee.png' class='cardimg'>", "<image src='images/spelling/dog.png' class='cardimg'>", "<image src='images/spelling/house.png' class='cardimg'>", "<image src='images/spelling/car.png' class='cardimg'>"];
        
    var descriptionOptions = ["cat", "bee", "dog", "house", "car"];


    function firstCard() {
        var title = document.getElementById("title");
        var description = document.getElementById("description");
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = titleOptions[0];
        document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = descriptionOptions[0];
        description.style.display = "none";
        if(title.style.display == "none") {
                title.style.display = "block";
          }
        if (titleOptions <= 0) {
        document.getElementById("completed").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("title").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("completed").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("title").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
        
    function showFront() {
        var title = document.getElementById("title");
        var description = document.getElementById("description");
        description.style.display = "none";
        if(title.style.display == "none") {
                title.style.display = "block";
          }
        else {
            title.style.display = "block";
        }
    }

    function showBack() {
        var title = document.getElementById("title");
        var description = document.getElementById("description");
        title.style.display = "none";
        if(description.style.display == "none") {
                description.style.display = "block";
          }
        else {
            description.style.display = "block";
        }
        if (descriptionOptions <= 0) {
        document.getElementById("completed").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("description").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("completed").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("description").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }

    function changeTitle() {
        titleOptions.shift();
        descriptionOptions.shift();
        var title = document.getElementById("title");
        var description = document.getElementById("description");
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = titleOptions[0];
        document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = descriptionOptions[0];
        description.style.display = "none";
        if(title.style.display == "none") {
                title.style.display = "block";
          }
        if (titleOptions <= 0) {
        document.getElementById("completed").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("title").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("completed").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("title").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title>Mrs. Katie's Grade One Online Classroom - Spelling</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    
</head>
    
<body onload="firstCard()">
    
    <header>
        <div id="headerwrapper">
            <img src="images/mrskatie.png" alt="Mrs. Katie" id="mrskatie">
            <h1>Mrs. Katie's</h1>
            <h2>Grade One Online Classroom</h2>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <div id="bodywrapper">
        <nav>
            <div class="rectangle">   
                <ul id="navigation">
                  
                  <li><a href="spelling.html" class="currentpage">Spelling</a></li>
                 
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="trianglecontainer">
                <div class="left-triangle-top"></div>
                <div class="left-triangle-bottom"></div>
                <div class="right-triangle-top"></div>
                <div class="right-triangle-bottom"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="card">
            <div id="buttonwrapper">
                <button onclick="showFront();">Front</button>
                <button onclick="showBack();">Back</button>
                <button onclick="changeTitle()" id="nextcard">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div id="textwrapper">
                <div id="title" style="display:block;"></div>
                <div id="description" style="display:none;"></div>
                <div id="completed"><img src="images/popupteacher.png" alt="You completed the cards! Great job." id="popupteacher">
                <a href="index.html" id="startover">Start Over</a><a href="#" id="nextsubject">Next Subject</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: What does your code do that isn't what you're expecting? Just tossing that much code up there doesn't help us. We don't have time to go through all of that and figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you are trying to set innerHTML with a Dom Html Element.

```
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = titleOptions[0];
```

That is not going to work. You need to append it.

```
var title = document.getElementById("title");
title.innerHTML = "";  //remove other elements
title.appendChild(titleOptions[0]);  //add the image
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Thanks to those of you who helped. That was all I needed.

```js
<script>
   
    var titleOptions = ["<image src='images/spelling/cat.png' class='cardimg'>", "<image src='images/spelling/bee.png' class='cardimg'>", "<image src='images/spelling/dog.png' class='cardimg'>", "<image src='images/spelling/house.png' class='cardimg'>", "<image src='images/spelling/car.png' class='cardimg'>"];
        
    var descriptionOptions = ["cat", "bee", "dog", "house", "car"];
    
    </script>
```